# How do I get tinyMCE editor instance by the element selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I want to set a content of tinyMCE editor after it was created with an AJAX request. I have several editors on page. All them are initialised with:

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: '.tiny-mce'
    });
```

Each editor has a distinct class to separate it from each other.
How do I use this class to set content to a one particular editor, after getting data with an AJAX request?

```
tinyMCE.get('.class_name') // returns null
```

I am searching API and SO and can't find a function to do such a simple thing.

Edit:

I found not so clean way to get the editor instance. When tinyMCE was created it added id with editor name to the element. Now I can do something like this:

```
var id = $('.class_name').attr('id');
tinyMCE.get(id).setContent('new content');
```

But is there a better way?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Per the `get()` API the string you pass to that call needs to be the **ID** of the editor element not a Class.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/class/tinymce/#get

So if you want to target the editor based on the ID you need something like this:

```
<textarea class='tiny-mce' id='editor1'></textarea>
<textarea class='tiny-mce' id='editor2'></textarea>
```

... and in your JavaScript something like this...

```
tinymce.get('editor2').setContent('...content here...');
```

If you only have one editor on the page you can also use

```
tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('...content here...');
```

**EDIT:**  It depends on **when** in the editor's lifecycle you want to call the `get()` or `activeEditor` methods.

These won't return anything until after TinyMCE is fully initialized.  If you have code like this:

```
<form method="post" action="dump.php">
    <textarea class='tiny-mce' id='editor1'></textarea>
    <textarea class='tiny-mce' id='editor2'></textarea>  
</form>
<script>
    tinymce.get('editor2').setContent("content here");
</script>
```

This will typically fail because you don't know if TinyMCE is finished initializing the textareas when your JavaScript is running.  Please see this fiddle:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/gufaab/1

The best way to load content into the editor is to use the editor's own "init" callback and place your code in there.  For example:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('init', function () {
             this.setContent('The init function knows on which editor its called - this is for ' + editor.id);
        });
    } 
});
```

...note that the init gets called for each editor (if there are multiple) and you have access to the editor object in the DOM if needed.

Comment: use id instead of classes - got it! Thanks!

Comment: actually, your method is not working. Accessing tinyMCE by the element id returns null.

Comment: @Boykodev - please see the updates to my post.  **When** you call these methods is important - if its returning `null` when you know you have the ID correct you are likely calling it before the editor is initialized and ready for interaction.  There are APIs you can use to address that issue.

Comment: tinymce.get('editor2').setContent('...content here...'); this works only when tinymce is in visual mode, does't work when tinymce in text mode. any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use id in the selector and set content after the editor is initialized with the callback function:

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea#tinymce1',
init_instance_callback : function(){
tinymce.get('tinymce1').setContent(data)
}
});
```

this is the html

```
<textarea id="tinymce1"></textarea>
```

use init_instance_callback because if you set the content with the ajax request it can goes faster than the initialization of the editor

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE works better when you use id selector instead of class selector.
You can use init_instance_callback to set your content when your editor is initialized.

This only works if you have an id selector.

**HTML :**

```
<textarea id="editor1"></textarea>
```

**JS :**

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea#editor1',
  init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
    editor.setContent("content here");
  }
});
```

OR

```
function setContent(editor) {
  editor.setContent("content here");
}

tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea#editor1',
  init_instance_callback: setContent
});
```